# Using Batik 1.14 with Java: How to import modules or classes?

Tags: java, svg, module, classpath, batik

The purpose of my project is to create PNG pictures from SVG using specific fonts (I have tried numerous converter services on the web but none of them worked with external fonts, and the JAVA program I have developed 10 years ago does no longer work).
My actual problem is the import of the **batik.transcoder** components into my program. Currently, it looks as follows:

```
<code>
    // is this the really the parent of JPEGTranscoder / PNGTranscoder??
    import javax.imageio.ImageTranscoder;  
    // Neither org.apache.batik... nor batik... is correct !!??
    import org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder;
    import batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
    import batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
    import batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
    import batik.transcoder.PNGTranscoder;
    import batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;<br>
    // or did I import the wrong jars ??
    // (taken from batik-1.14 and afterwards from batik-1.7; neither did work!)
    public class SVGConverter {
    ...
      // all code lines below return the same error: "... cannot be resolved to a type"
      TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);
      TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

      ImageTranscoder t;
    ...
      t = new JPEGTranscoder();
    ...
      t = new PNGTranscoder();
    ...
    }
</code>
```

First I tried to import the batik components as modules on the module path but without success. In a contribution to stackoverflow I then found the hint to put the batik components not onto the module path but to the class path (Has batik not been converted into modules?). However, no success either.
I have copied all jar's contained in batik-1.14.zip and later of batik-1.7.zip into the lib directory within the project. No effect whatsoever...
I was using "import org.apache.batik.transcoder.XXX" in my previous program in 2013: Doesn't work any more. But using "import batik.transcoder.XXX" doesn't work either.
Thus, the following questions:
**1. Is it correct that batik classes/jars have to be used via the class path?

2. What is the correct package name to address the respective packages and classes?

3. Is it correct to load the corresponding jar's into the lib directory of the project?**